# SSH local port forward can not access from outside

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, portforwarding

After

```
server-a$ ssh -L 9000:imgur.com:80 user@example.com
```

I can only

```
server-a$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9000
```

from the server-a, can not access 9000 port of server-a from outside.

How can I access the server-a 9000 from outside, I don't have any iptables ?

PS: I meet this problem before, after I edit the sshd_config, this problem was fixed, but I don't remember what I changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add -g to the command

```
ssh -g -L 9000:imgur.com:80 user@example.com
```

From ssh man:

-g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.

means ssh will listen on other IP then localhost enabling you to connect to the forwarded port from outside your system.

This is not on by default because it can be a security issue (random people connecting to the forwarded port arriving on the supposedly secured destination server)

Comment: Care to elaborate on what the `-g` flag does?

Comment: Hehe, sorry :-) man ssh says:      -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.